# Fragment in Viewpager is not scrolling upwards

Tags: android

I have a viewpager consisting of 3 fragments. The first two fragments are simply recyclerViews and they scroll upwards perfectly. However in my third fragment, it's a linear layout and it doesn't scroll upwards:

The first two fragment layouts are just recyclers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

The third fragment that is not scrolling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
```

My viewpager layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragprofile_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //Collapsing toolbar, etc

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragprofile_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: LinearLayout is not scrollable ViewGroup. You should put your LinearLayout inside a `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the root `LinearLayout` with `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView`.

**Note 1:** Android layouts are not scrollable by default.

**Note 2:** `ScrollView` and `NestedScrollView` must have only one direct child (should be a layout of some sort such as a `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`)

Hope this helps.